# On click expand li element 100% width and push siblings out

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to have li elements arranged in an arbitrary number of columns.

[image]

```
<ul>
    <li class="yellow">
        Yellow Block
    </li>
    <li class="red">
        Red Block
    </li>
    <li class="green">
        Green Block
    </li>
</ul>
```

When one of the columns is clicked I want that li to grow to 100% and its siblings to be pushed out of view.

```
$('li').on("click", function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().addClass("nonActive");
})
```

I am using the term "pushed of of view" loosely though as that is just the desired visual effect, the animation could involve pushing/movement, hiding, or width changes whichever looks cleanest.

## What I've tried:

**Setting clicked width to 100%, siblings to 0%:**

https://jsfiddle.net/bo28dy10/

```
.active{
    width: 100%;
}
.nonActive{
    width 0%;
}
```

Problem: causes word wrap as it shrinks, can't set no-wrap as some cases the labels are intended to wrap at full width.

**Setting clicked width to 100%, setting the wrapper to overflow: hidden**:
https://jsfiddle.net/gqqeq4wu/

```
.active{
    width: 100%;
}
ul{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Problem: This just forces the siblings down a row instead of pushing them out, I'm not able to set a fixed height on the parent.

**Setting clicked width to 100%, setting siblings to display:none**:
https://jsfiddle.net/xf0om99t/

```
.active{
    width: 100%;
}
.nonActive{
    display:none;
}
```

Problem: You can't use animations on display:none, I want this to be a smooth transition.

**So what is the correct way to simulate this look?**

(bonus: If I could get rid of the column widths (i.e. 33.33%) and just have these columns expand automatically to fill the parent equally that would be wonderful, I'm thinking flexbox perhaps?)

Comment: why "push" them out of view? It'd be far easier to just `.hide()` the other siblings, so they're no longer part of the layout calculations.

Comment: @MarcB That's essentially what I tried in the third fiddle, I want to animate these out which you can't do with display:none, so they disappear abruptly and snap the active element to the left. If there is a better way to do it though I would appreciate it.

Comment: then use a css transition to animate their width down to 0.

Comment: @MarcB Thats what I did in the first fiddle...

Comment: Flexbox can help but the text wrapping is still an issue, - https://jsfiddle.net/bo28dy10/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used jQuery to set the min-width of each li. I've added a div to show it works with various number of li.

```
liLen = $( "ul" ).width()/$( "li" ).length
$("li").children('div').css("min-width", liLen+"px");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bo28dy10/4/

Comment: Very nice, that is exactly how I was hoping it'd look. A bit more complicated but I think it's worth it. I personally would simplify the .js a bit, `$("li").children('div').css("min-width", $("li").width());` would accomplish the same things in this scenario. I'm going to give a little more time to see if CSS only solutions come in but will accept this if not. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You were nearly there

```
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
```

does the trick. nice and smooth

see here

https://jsfiddle.net/bo28dy10/2/

Comment: This was my first thought, until I read up to "can't set no-wrap as some cases the labels are intended to wrap at full width".

Comment: @RouthMedia Yes unfortunately I would like to avoid setting nowrap, some situation could call for a larger text label. I appreciate the effort though.

Comment: I was going for the answer which involved not reading the entire question! :)

Comment: @RouthMedia No worries, in most scenarios I believe this would be the correct one I'm just in a picky situation.

Answer (score 1):

What if we try something as below by using margin-right and opacity.

```js
$('li').on("click", function(){
 $(this).addClass("active");
  $(this).siblings().addClass("nonActive");
})
```

```css
ul{
  width: 400px;
  list-style-type: none; 
}
li{
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.6s all;
}
.red{
  background: red;
}
.yellow{
  background: yellow;
}
.green{
  background: green;
}
.active{
  width: 100%;
}
.nonActive{
  margin-right:-400px;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="yellow">
Yellow Block
</li>
<li class="red">
Red Block
</li>
<li class="green">
Green Block
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not bad it does maintain some of the animation for the siblings compared to just hiding them, I am just not too fond of the look. I appreciate it though and will keep it in mind. +1

Comment: Okay @DasBeasto but if we work-out bit could get some pushing them out effects :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the width, padding and font-size of the siblings :

```js
$('li').on("click", function(){
 $(this).addClass("active");
  $(this).siblings().addClass("nonActive");
})
```

```css
ul{
  width: 400px;
  list-style-type: none; 
}
li{
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.6s all;
}
.red{
  background: red;
}
.yellow{
  background: yellow;
}
.green{
  background: green;
}
.active{
  width: 100%;
}
.nonActive{
  padding: 23px 0px;
  width:0;
  font-size:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="yellow">
Yellow Block
</li>
<li class="red">
Red Block
</li>
<li class="green">
Green Block
</li>
</ul>
```